# dimension of $U_{p,q}$ the pseudo unitary group

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

Dimension of the pseudo unitary group is $(p+q)^2$ where $U_{p,q} = M ∈ M_{p+q} (\Bbb C) : ^tMJ_{p,q}M = J_{p,q}.$ where $J_{p,q}=Diag(1...1,-1...-1)$ with $1\ p$ times and $-1\ q$ times.

How can we see that the dimension of this group is $(p+q)^2$? I can't see any reference or proof of this?

What about the dimension of $SU_{p,q}$?

Thank you for your help

Comment: One can compute the Lie algebra and from there it is easier to see the dimension. Also the groups $SU(p,q)$ are inner forms of $SL(p+q)$ and hence are all of the same dimension as $SL(p+q)$. Either of these ways should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U(p,q) = \lbrace M \in M_{p+q}(\mathbb{C}) | ^t\overline{M}JM = J \rbrace$. One can compute the Lie algebra to be

$\mathfrak{u}(p,q) = \lbrace M \in M(p,q) | ^t\overline{M}J + JM = 0 \rbrace$. Now we will compute the explicit form as block matrix as below.

$M = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end{bmatrix}$.

One can compute with above equations to get that the $M \in \mathfrak{u}(p,q)$ if and only if the matrix $M$ satisfies

$A + (^t\overline{A}) = 0 = D + (^t\overline{D})$ and $B = (^t\overline{C})$. That is $A \in \mathfrak{u}(p)$, $D \in \mathfrak{u}(q)$ and $B$ is any $p \times q$ matrix with complex entries. Now the only thing left is to add up the dimension of the spaces of matrices $A,B$ and $D$ which are $p^2, 2pq$ and $q^2$ respectively. Thus we have the answer.

One can caluculate the dimension of $SU(p,q)$ from here. Since the condition of determinant one imposes a linear equation in the Lie algebra of matrices having trace zero.

Comment: I think dimension of $SU(p,q)$ is $(p+q)^2-1$?

Comment: @PerelMan Yes. That is correct. The last paragraph of the answer translates to the fact that dimension of $SU(p,q)$ is one less than the dimension of $U(p,q)$.

Comment: Many thanks! I made also the same calculations using the block matrices and I found that $B=^t\overline{C}$... But that is minor

Comment: @PerelMan Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have edited the answer accordingly.